# Does a backbone.js model render?

Tags: backbone.js

from what i understand so far using twitter as an example, a single tweet would be a model then the backbone view would render the collection of models. So would the model render or would i make a separate view to render that model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Backbone.js, there are collections and models. A collection contains more than one model of the same type. If you take twitter as an example, a single tweet may be considered as a model and the the list of tweets can be considered as a collection. Both the collection and model have views associated with them. **It is this view that gets rendered and not the model/collection.** A view for a collection may contain multiple number of views of the model that it holds. For example, the twitter feed(Collection) on on your Twitter home page is the view associated with the collection of tweets and each block that represents a tweet is the view corresponding to a single tweet(Model)

Comment: thanks for simplifying it, you made it so easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

For example:
A model could be a single tweet.
A collections could be a bunch of tweets.

The render cycle:

1. User click on "Show me a bunch of tweets".
2. Your view is fetching the BunchOfTweet collection (it means the collection call the api).
3. When the collection receive the results (a array of models/tweets) it will tigger an event "change".
4. your view is listening to "change" for this collection and then trigger  the render function.

Ask for new data => Fetch data => re-render

I hope this cycle is clearer now.